# Database not having unique ID's

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I have a database containing attendance in monthly basis. Now, I want to display that data on a series of text box. But my problem is that it does not contain any unique id's that's making my task difficult. Have a look at the attachment so that you guys can get the picture of my problem.

http://s26.postimg.org/p8v0zhemx/image.png

Thank you so much in advance.

EDIT: 
For future researchers using listview, this is the query for my MySQL.

1. You have to make a composite key if your db does not have a unique id. Google it.
2. The query i managed to pull out from my head.

   `"SELECT empno, line1, time1, line2, time2, line3, time3, line4, time4, line5, time5, line6, time6 FROM attendancelist WHERE empno = '" & ListPayroll.SelectedItems(0).Text & "' AND line1 = '" & ListPayroll.SelectedItems(0).SubItems(1).Text & "'"`

Comment: You probably should add id's to your table

Comment: We can't perform magic.  If there's no way to uniquely identify a record then there's no way to find a specific record.  Either you retrieve all the data and let the user navigate through it at their will or you determine a way to identify a record.  Maybe you have to let them search using multiple criteria and just retrieve multiple matching records if there are indeed multiple matches.

Comment: That's what I'm thinking, but how can i do it? Please advise me.

Comment: This table does not look very normalized. You have multiple pieces of information inside single columns. Not to mention the "Week #" and "Time" columns seem repetitive. A better designed schema would probably make this problem simpler. At the very least, the process of normalizing it would give you a clearer picture of the data you're storing. Also, your question doesn't make it clear how a unique ID would help you to begin with.

Comment: while an individual column might not be unique the combination of two or more columns may be, for instance employee id and week 1 seem to create a unique combination

Comment: @elcabronel Your picture does show a unique ID, doesn't it? The data under Employee Number is unique right? Of course not in this table that contains attendance, which should have redundant Employee Number. What seems to the real problem?

Comment: Thank you so much for all the ideas!

Comment: @theDarse your idea might just fit what i'm trying to achieve. Again, thank you so much.

Comment: @jpmc26 its not my database design, its from a chinise software company(no support coming from them) and that data we are looking at is from a biometrics machine. A unique ID will greatly help me in my project because querying specific data will be much easier. I'm thinking of how to input a unique ID for each of the record. But theDarse's idea might just work.

Comment: @chris_techno25 this is from phpmyadmin http://s26.postimg.org/nv3e46fdl/image.png

Comment: You can create an automatically incrementing surrogate key to provide a unique ID, but your question still doesn't explain what problem it solves for you. Surrogate keys are mostly useful as foreign key references and not much else (so far as I know, anyway). If you explain *why* you need a unique ID, we can probably be more helpful.

Comment: @elcabronel Is this the only table you have? If it is, you can create a new table with unique ids matching to the 2nd table's empno using the GROUP BY clause, you should then have 2 tables. 1 table containing unique IDs and the second table being the support table for table 1 as attendance information :)

Comment: @jpmc26 Having a unique ID might be the only way to edit,delete,insert specific data from that database and might just help for the printing of attendance and for calculating the payroll of each employee.

Comment: @chris_techno25 great idea bro, but how? for example (table 1 will contain empno = '00001' and table 2 will have empID = '00001a'?)

Comment: Again great ideas started to sink in, i really really appreciate it. Thank you guys. :)

Comment: @elcabronel I've actually used something like your device. I know documentations of some Chinese devices, especially OEM, are not very friendly. So judging from the picture you showed, empno should be the ID generated from the biometrics device, so this should be unique, in the sense that '00001' data belongs to '00001' itself. So you can 'SELECT empno FROM OriginalTable GROUP BY empno;' This should give you all the IDs, plus it's grouped so you won't see any redundancy. Then can you insert the rows into a new table :)

Comment: Yes! The database design of the system that came up with the biometrics are awfully not so friendly. Searching for an specific empno gives no problem. But what if i edit or delete it? Then the rest of the data will also be edited/deleted because they're having the same empno. That's the problem i'm facing right now. :) @chris_techno25 thank you so much for giving me ideas and solution to this dreadful problem. :)

Comment: Note that you don't want to use any columns the user might be editing for unique identification. They might edit it so that it's no longer unique. (If you constrain it, they would get a very strange error message.)

Comment: @elcabronel Well don't thank us yet, the problem isn't solved yet :) Anyways, if you'd like to delete a single row against the original table, deleting with 2 conditions connected by AND should do the trick, theDarse did state that the combination of empno and week 1 can be unique.

Comment: `Dim query As String = "SELECT empno, line1, time1, line2, time2, line3, time3, line4, time4, line5, time5, line6, time6 FROM attendancelist WHERE empno = '" & ListPayroll.SelectedItems(0).Text & "'"`this is the query (this works fine) how can i append the AND?

Comment: Just dropping by to say that i solve my problem creating a Composite Key. :) Thank you everyone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to me like your sample data table contains tons of attendance data that basically look like this:

```
 employee     workdate    starttime   endtime   
  00117     2014-02-03     08:15        17:30   
  00117     2014-02-04     09:00        17:30  
  00117     2014-02-05      null         null  
  etc.
```

If the employee was absent on the given day, that's indicated by null values in starttime and endtime.  If the employee was not employed at all on the particular date, you'd simply leave the row out of the table entirely. I think that's what the first five days of employee 00001 in your sample data's first row mean -- not present, not absent.

Your raw data is arranged in a pretty doggone inconvenient report layout that puts a week's work of days on each row. You can probably write a simple dotnet program to slurp up your six-day-week input table and insert six rows (or fewer) of this data from each row of that table.

Once you've loaded your data from that input table, you can switch over to maintaining it in your new table. That will be much easier for you to handle in a program. You will also be able to write a query program that will recreate your six-day-row report, if that's what your users prefer.

Arranged the way I have shown it, you'll get a nice little attendance table.  If you know ahead of time you'll have at most one record per day per employee, you can use the columns I've shown, and use a composite primary key consisting of (employee, workdate).

If you might have more than one row per employee per date you'll need to add an id column, that can be an autoincrementing surrogate primary key.

Comment: Another great idea! Thank you so much. I will try to revise the db design so that it would fit right for the normal users.

Comment: Just dropping by to say that i solve my problem creating a Composite Key. :) Thank you everyone!

Answer (score 0):

If all you need is an arbitrary unique identifier for update and delete (as indicated in the comments), then add one:

```
ALTER TABLE my_table
ADD COLUMN id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY;
```

That is, of course, assuming you have that ability or can convince someone who does. It is a remarkably minor change. If column names are specified in the existing `INSERT` queries, it won't require a change to them. Someone ought to be willing to do it.

If you have the freedom to modify the schema, please consider revising it. This is very, very poorly designed (having repetitive columns and columns containing multiple pieces of information). If you cannot modify this one, creating a new, better designed schema and importing data from this schema may be another option you want to consider. (Creating a "new schema" could also be accomplished using a set of separate tables.)

Also be aware that with the current structure, you will need extremely heavy validation code side to prevent users from saving invalid data when they modify it.

Comment: Creating a new schema and importing from that current db is also a great idea. Thank you. I'm making a payroll system that has admin and reg user so that would be no problem to me. Only admin accounts can modify data from the system. :)

Comment: I would argue it doesn't matter whether your users are "admins" or not. In the current format, it would still be very, very easy to typo the data and break your application (make it throw errors on later queries). If you create a revised schema, you'll have more opportunities to enforce data integrity database side, of course. Ollie's recommendation about structure is roughly what I had in mind for this particular table.

Comment: Thank you! I will try to make another schema and import data from the previous one.

Comment: Just dropping by to say that i solve my problem creating a Composite Key. :) Thank you everyone!